Querying shallow cloned Delta table from Athena
Athena supports querying Delta tables on s3. Wanted to know whether it is possible to query a shallow-cloned Delta table, which is hosted on S3 and managed externally (i.e., without using Databricks), using Amazon Athena.
Cloned delta table to a new location and ran crawler on this new location, but querying on crawler created table in athena fails with below error:

GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Failed to generate splits for deltalake.clone-table

